# PHPMyAdmin - built in edit query failing

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Whenever I am pressing the `Edit` key on PHPMyAdmin I am getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

The query it is referring to is the in built function of PHPMyAdmin so I do not understand why this is failing. This is the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM `self`.`Condition` WHERE LIMIT 0, 30
```

[image]

Comment: Remove WHERE keyword.

Comment: Remove WHERE or add a condition

Comment: Is it possible to edit the built in commands of PHPMyAdmin? I realise I can enter this query manually but I don't understand why a built in function would have this error.

Comment: When I enter the query minus the `WHERE` clause it returns the values of the `Condition` table but I am looking to edit the values of the table.

Comment: @ColinShewell a Select command is for viewing data. If you want to edit it, you need an Update command. If you want to add data, you need an Insert command. PHPMyAdmin also has built-in GUI for editing data which should generate the scripts for you based on what you type in the textboxes. P.S. I doubt that pressing the "Edit" key is generating a SELECT statement, somehow.

Comment: I'll update my original question showing the error that is produced when the `edit` is pressed....

Comment: If you check the checkbox and press edit does it work?

Comment: It gives the same error.

Comment: I get it now. Does your table have a primary key? It might be struggling to know how to generate the WHERE clause if not.

Comment: `ID` is marked as the primary key.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version do you have? This sounds like it may be related to a bug that was fixed several versions ago.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is error . try this

```
SELECT * FROM `table-name` WHERE `Condition` LIMIT 0, 30
```

example

```
SELECT * FROM `Orders` WHERE `company-name="HP"` LIMIT 0, 30
```